# pandas: groupby respecting conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe below with date, id, revenue.

example of dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """date,id,revenue
2021-05-05,X1,50
2021-05-05,X2,30
2021-05-05,X3,20
2021-05-06,X1,300
2021-05-06,X2,500
2021-05-01,X1,5"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

I want to do some classification and calculate for each date, the number of persons (id) if revenue is respecting some conditions.
Count nbr of clients (id) if revenue is between 0 and 10.
Count nbr of clients (id) if revenue is between 20 and 50.
Count nbr of clients (id) if revenue is between 100 and 1000.

In my case the **expected output** should be

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """date,id,revenue, interval
2021-05-05,X1,50, 3
2021-05-05,X2,30, 3
2021-05-05,X3,20, 3
2021-05-06,X1,300, 2
2021-05-06,X2,500, 2
2021-05-01,X1,5, 1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Comment: Do you want one column of three columns? 0 - 10, 20 - 50 and 100 - 1000?

Comment: yes @tomjn like i put in the **expected output**

Comment: Use `pd.cut` for your binning then use groupby for aggregation

Comment: @i did it with pd.cut thank you :)

Comment: @biwia if you thought my answer useful, please accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to cut your data.

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['revenue'], bins=
    pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 10), (20, 50), (100, 1000)], closed='both'))
```

The data frame now looks like this:

```
         date  id  revenue         bins
0  2021-05-05  X1       50     [20, 50]
1  2021-05-05  X2       30     [20, 50]
2  2021-05-05  X3       20     [20, 50]
3  2021-05-06  X1      300  [100, 1000]
4  2021-05-06  X2      500  [100, 1000]
5  2021-05-01  X1        5      [0, 10]
```

To cut properly, create an interval index which includes the bounds (ie, passing `closed='both'`). This all needs to be specified explicitly rather than with just a list of scalars, because of the bound-inclusivity. Note that you'll get unexpected output if your revenue falls outside one of these discontinuous intervals, eg, if revenue is 75.

Then just groupby and count.

```
bin_count = df.groupby('bins')['id'].count()
```

`bin_count` looks like this:

```
[0, 10]        1
[20, 50]       3
[100, 1000]    2
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

If you want to join the numbers back to your data frame, which seems to be what you have in your expected output under the name `interval` (which is a misnomer, use a different name) use `pd.Series.map` from the bins: `df['bin_count'] = df['bins'].map(bin_count)`.